# can I set the web.config file to read only?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, config

Would it cause any trouble to set the web.config file to read only? I ask this because I stupidly overwrote the file on an asp.net page that I had been maintaining and it screwed things up. I'd like to avoid that in the future, but I am not sure if it will just create a whole 'nother problem.

Thanks

Comment: no you can not - you may try, but you probably get an exception the first time your application try to start.... so try it.

Comment: You've asked an XY problem. You want to make the file read only, but the real problem is probably that you're not using a source controlled and automated process to deploy your application. You should practically never be hand modifying any deployed files. That should all be done via your deployment tool, such as [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/), [TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/) or [Octopus](https://octopus.com/) etc. If something were to happen to the deployed files that messes them up, you could simply redeploy.